# Adding Parent Tags using jQuery's $.fn.wrap

Tags: jquery

I'm creating all HTML elements using jQuery, and I'm trying to wrap parent `div#wrapDivTag` using `$.fn.wrap` but it is not working for me:

jQuery:

```
var wrapDivTag = $("<div class='wrapDivTag'></div>");
var actionName = $("<span>text1</span>");
var text = $("<div>Text2</div>")
var ddl = $("<select>Text2</select>")

$("#addconfigurations").append(actionName, text, ddl);
```

HTML Output:

```
<span>text1<span>
<div>text2<div>
<select>options</select>
```

Exptected Output:

HTML elements should be under the `div#wrapDivTag` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var wrapDivTag = $("<div class='wrapDivTag'></div>");

var actionName = $("<span>text1</span>");
var text = $("<div>Text2</div>")
var ddl = $("<select>Text2</select>");

wrapDivTag.append(actionName, text,ddl); // append all element to #wrapDivTag

$("#addconfigurations").append(wrapDivTag); // append wrap div to target
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) method:

```
$("#addconfigurations").append(actionName, text, ddl).children().wrapAll(wrapDivTag);
```

Or inverted version using [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
wrapDivTag.append(actionName, text, ddl).appendTo("#addconfigurations");
```